# From master branch i created new branch called release1

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, branching-and-merging

From master branch i created new branch called release1. I switched to release1 branch and added one file then again i switched to master branch.Here without merging branch,the file which is in release1 branch is reflecting in master branch why?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add/commit your new file, it is moved as a pending modification to whichever branch you'll switch to.

To avoid this, commit on your `release1` branch *before* switching back to `master` and it'll "stay" there.